# How to specify which columns to load in pyarrow.dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to get only the columns what I want, like how we do in pandas.

```
use_cols = ["ArrDelay", "DepDelay"]
df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=use_cols)
df
```

Is there an option similar to that in arrow ?

```
dataset = ds.dataset(path, format="csv")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want is...

```
table = dataset.to_table(columns=["ArrDelay", "DepDelay"])
```

The dataset methods `scan()`, `to_batches()`, and `to_tables()` all take the same arguments, which are documented on the [`scan()`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.scan) method.